# Cannot set the input value using e.Value = "value" in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a simple `input` with the type `text`:

```
<input type="text" @oninput="Input_OnInput" />
```

As you can see, the `oninput` event is handled by the `Input_OnInput` method. Here's its implementation:

```
private void Input_OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    string inputValue = e.Value.ToString();
    e.Value = inputValue + "ABC";
}
```

All it does is it appends three characters to the input string and then assigns the new string to the `e.Value` property.

However, for some reason that I'm unable to understand, this doesn't work, and the new string is not shown in the input text on the UI.

BTW, perhaps I should mention that the method DOES get called, and that specific line DOES get executed, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'm using Blazor server-side hosting model, if that matters.

Comment: `e.Value` is a one-way street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you're supposed to update a input in Blazor, please review

Sample code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
<p>
    <input @bind="currentValue" /> Current value: @currentValue
</p>

<p>
    <input @bind="CurrentValue" /> Current value: @CurrentValue
</p>

@code {
    private string currentValue;

    private string CurrentValue { get; set; }
}
```